# TypeError: NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to extract 2 subsets from a DataFrame "raw_DF" based on some columns null values. 1st subset contains data with non-null values, and the other one is populated with null values. This code works well with Python v3.8 and Pandas v1.0.5.

But, it gives below mentioned error message with Python v3.11 and Pandas v2.0.3. Due to some reasons, I can't move back to Python v3.8. Please help me to troubleshoot this issue.

**Python Script**

```
raw_DF=pd.read_excel(raw_file_Ex, sheet_name='Data',usecols=['Details','Date','FOLDER NAME','FILE NAME','STORE NAME','BRAND','ITEM NAME','SIZE','SEASON','BARCODE/ITEMCODE','ITEM MRP','QTY','MRP VALUE','DISTRIBUTOR','REMARKS'], 
        parse_dates=['Date'],dtype={'Details':str,'FOLDER NAME':str,'FILE NAME':str,'STORE NAME':str,'BRAND':str,'ITEM NAME':str,'SIZE':str,'SEASON':str,'BARCODE/ITEMCODE':str,'ITEM MRP':float,'QTY':int,'MRP VALUE':float,'DISTRIBUTOR':str,'REMARKS':str})

step_num+=1
print(f'{step_num}.\tValidating and formatting data frames: {dt.now().strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H %M %S")}')


if raw_DF.isnull().values.any():
    good_data = raw_DF[raw_DF[['Details','Date','BRAND','BARCODE/ITEMCODE','QTY','MRP VALUE','DISTRIBUTOR']].notnull().all(1)]
    bad_data = raw_DF[raw_DF[['Details','Date','BRAND','BARCODE/ITEMCODE','QTY','MRP VALUE','DISTRIBUTOR']].isnull().any(1)]
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\reconciler_v2.py", line 39, in <module>
    bad_data = raw_DF[raw_DF[['Details','Date','BRAND','BARCODE/ITEMCODE','QTY','MRP VALUE','DISTRIBUTOR']].isnull().any(1)]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
PS ..\Reconciler>
```

Comment: Instead of `any(1)`, you likely want `any(axis=1)`.